# Nested Include not Working in Rails 4 during rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
@test = Test.find(params[:test_id].to_i)
group_tests_id = @test.group_tests.map(&:group_id)
@std = Student.joins(:group_students).where("group_id IN (?)",group_tests_id).uniq
render :json => {:students => @std.as_json(include: [:user.as_json(only: [:id, :first_name])]), :test => @test.as_json()}
```

Every thing working fine.

I'm getting this result

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 38,
            "user_id": 34,
            "created_at": "2017-08-07T12:30:02.120+05:00",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-07T12:30:02.120+05:00",
            "user": {
                "id": 34,
                "username": "taimoor123",
                "created_at": "2017-08-07T12:30:02.067+05:00",
                "updated_at": "2017-08-07T12:33:19.273+05:00",
                "first_name": "Muhammad Taimoor",
                "second_name": "Sultani",
                "school_name": "Moon Public School",
                "section_name": "Blue 10th",
                "gender": "Male",
                "age": 23,
                "role": "Student",
                "school_id": 1,
                "section_id": 2,           
            }
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "id": 33,
        "name": "Test 8/7/2017",
        "attempt_time": 15,
        "teacher_id": 1
    }
}
```

But I just want `id` and `first_name` of `user` in `student` object.
I'm confuse that why nested include is not working here.
Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
render :json => {:students => @std.as_json(include: [:user.as_json(only: [:id, :first_name])]), :test => @test.as_json()}
```

According to the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json), nesting inclusion is performed by:

```
object.as_json(include: { nested_object: { only: [:nested_object_field] } })
```

Hence, you'll need to correct the line to:

```
render :json => {:students => @std.as_json(include: { user: { only: [:id, :first_name] } }), :test => @test.as_json()}
```

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for Your help.